# jQuery image slider with animation

Tags: jquery, html, image, slider

I need one help for jquery slider. I made slider like this (myFunc() is function that pull one random image from array. Example: array['picture1.jpg', 'picture2.jpg']....

```
$('.img').click(function (){
        var link = pathOne + myFunc();
            $('.img').hide("slide", { direction: "down" }, 250, function(){
        var link = pathOne + myFunc();
            $('.img').show("slide", { direction: "up" }, 250).attr("src",preFolder + link).stop();
    });
});
```

so on click images hides, and then shows again. My question is how i can make slider to show random images, one followed by another. like this example http://jsfiddle.net/EjZzs/15/

In my case, im must wait to picture hide, and appear another one.

Comment: So, given an array of paths to images, you need to choose one of those paths at random to put into the `.attr()` call?

Comment: That works everything, i only need a way to animate random pictures , like om the link http://jsfiddle.net/EjZzs/15/

Answer (score 0):

First, you have an array as you specified:

```
var images = ['picture1.jpg', 'picture2.jpg', 'picture3.jpg'];
```

Then, you need to generate a random number between 0 and `images.length-1`. [This answer][1] tells you how to get a random number in a certain range:

```
function randomIntFromInterval(min,max)
{
    return Math.floor(Math.random()*(max-min+1)+min);
}
```

You can get a random entry in the array like this:

```
var randomImage = images[randomIntFromInterval(0, images.length)];
```

Comment: I have that function, i just need how to do animation with that random pictures? like animation in the link i posted